# Get total 'objects' from a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing

If a have a string like this:  `var myString="{text} and {text1} are going to {text2}."`

How can I get the total number of {text} in `C#`? **In my case : 3**

I'm thinking at `regex`but I don't know how to write to match `{text}`.

**EDIT :** 
I need {text} instead of {number}

Comment: Counting `{` or `}` won't work ?

Comment: I'm trying to make a string.Format for an anonymous objects and if I have more {x} in the string I want to throw an exception..  Also I can have a string like this "{{1}}  and {2}" . So counting them doesn't work

Comment: @Kosmo - remember that it is *possible* to reference the same parameter in more than one position in a format string - so what should `{0}, {1} and {0} again` count as? 2 or 3?

Comment: @Kosmo: I don't understand what is your goal. Can you show us a practical example of expected behavior?

Comment: For exameple if I have an anonymous object var myObject = new {firstName="MMM", lastName="BBB" } and a string My name is {firstName} {lastName} it should return My name is MMM NNN. I wanted to verify my string if it contains enough {text} for my object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to espace the brackets :

```
\{\d+\}
```

and in C#:

```
var count = Regex.Matches( yourstring, @"\{\d+\}").Count;
```

To improve your regex skills, I advise you to play with http://regexlib.net/RETester.aspx

Comment: Before editing the question your answer was ok, so I'll accept it and I'll try to adapt it for my situation. Thank you.

Comment: This regular expression is of course not going to match `{text}`.

Comment: Yes. I know. I have edited my question. Before I wanted to match numbers from brackets

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the string and count the number of { maybe?

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<myString.Length;i++)
{
   if(myString.CharAt(i)=='{')
   {
      count++
   }
}
```

Comment: and what is a proper answer?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Comment: @user1991181: A proper answer is the one that would output `"asd { qwe  {ttt}"` - 0 counts for that string. Your would return 2

Comment: wait so any answer that's LEADING to the solution but not the EXACT solution is not an answer right? this is ridiculous.

Comment: @zerkms, no Zerkms. That would be a correct answer. Pardon me that Kosmo only specified further AFTER I posted my answer.

Comment: Yes. I posted an answer at the very beginning. And then Kosmo specified the following in a comment "I'm trying to make a string.Format for an anonymous objects and if I have more {x} in the string I want to throw an exception.. Also I can have a string like this "{{1}} and {2}" . So counting them doesn't work". Had I known this particular test case I wouldn't have posted that answer. Jesus Christ.

Answer (score 2):

Try this line of code (answer updated after question edited) - now matching any text in curly brackets:

```
Regex.Matches(myString, @"\{[^}]+\}").Count
```